# Pulling windows base images fails

Tags: docker, windows

I tried pulling the windows/nanoserver image.
After that failed I looked around and found [this site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/container-base-images)
Every one of them fails with the same error message

```
#docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1909
ltsc2019: Pulling from windows/servercore
no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries
```

Additional Info:
Docker version: 18.09.2, build 6247962
Win10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB: Version 10.0.14393 Build 14393

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is twofold:

- The Win10 LTSB is on its newest version and Docker has stopped supporting this version.
  This stops Docker from updating.
- Microsoft has moved to its own container registry and in doing so abandoned support for older Docker versions. So while I was pulling from the right registry it could not find a fitting image.

**Solution:** get an up-to-date, non-LTSB version of Windows

Additional Info:
While the error message did not help in finding the cause the docker log did:

```
[WindowsDaemon  ][Info   ] debug: a Windows version 10.0.18363-based image is incompatible with a 10.0.14393 host
```

Answer (score 0):

seems support ended for above mentioned image its no longer in their registry maybe

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-container-images-now-published-to-microsoft-container-registry/

Comment: While they stopped using the docker CR, the docker pages for the images list the correct link to mcr.microsoft.com